# What is the data source for filteredUsers should be in my TableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am working on iOS project using **Swift** and I am trying to add a **search bar** to my **TableViewController**

This is my code:

the properties part:

```
var UserNamesArray: NSMutableArray = []
```

and

```
var filteredUsers = [UserNamesArray]()
```

When I add the previous line it give me an error:  **instance member 'UserNamesArray' cannot used on type 'MyTableVC'** .

So this is the problem, what can I put instead of `[UserNamesArray]`?

viewDidLoad function:

```
    ref.queryOrderedByChild("Job").queryEqualToValue("Programers")
        .observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? NSMutableDictionary{
                print("dict====== \(dict)")

                for (key,value) in dict {
                    let mainDict = NSMutableDictionary()
                    mainDict.setObject(key, forKey: "userid")
                    if let dictnew = value as? NSMutableDictionary{
                        if let metname = dictnew["UserName"] as? String
                        {
                            mainDict.setObject(metname, forKey: "UserName")
                        }
                        if let metname = dictnew["Details"] as? String
                        {
                            mainDict.setObject(metname, forKey: "Details")
                        }
                        if let metname = dictnew["Email"] as? String
                        {
                            mainDict.setObject(metname, forKey: "Email")
                        }
                    }
                    print("mainDict========= \(mainDict)")

                    self.UserNamesArray.addObject(mainDict)
                }
                print("UserNamesArray ==== \(self.UserNamesArray)")
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        })
}
```

To make it clear, I took a screen shot of values of the variables:

1) dict  2) mainDict  3) UserNamesArray
[Please, click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFDlt.png)

That what my table view controller look like:
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7yIE.png)

I attempted to make it clear as I can I hope that someone can help. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `filteredUsers` supposed to be? What kind of objects do you want to put in that array?

Comment: If it just contains names (`String` objects), then you should declare the array like this: `var filteredUsers = [String]()`.  Right now you're declaring your array to have objects of type `UserNamesArray`, but that's not a type, that's just your object variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var filteredUsers = [UserNamesArray]()` doesn't work because `UserNamesArray` is not a valid type, it's just an object.

For example in the syntax `var foo = [Bar]()`, `Bar` is the type of the objects in the array `foo`.

So if `filteredUsers` is meant to hold an array of `String` objects then what you want is:

```
var filteredUsers = [String]()
```